# Configure Vertica DB log to send syslog server

Tags: linux, vertica, syslog, rsyslog, qradar

I am very new to Vertica DB. I want to send the vertica.log to remotehost through syslog. I need the steps to with respect to DB and OS.

Please help me to complete my task.

I need the complete steps to withrespect to DB aswell as OS.

Comment: I suggest you go to Vertica's documentation to understand what you can do from Vertica's side: https://docs.vertica.com/23.4.x/en/admin/monitoring/ . Vertica indeed logs to vertica.log - and zips vertica.log, adding a date to the file name, at regular intervals. You can move all vertica.log-YYYYMMDD.gz files with a log file handler al you like. But I would also look at all the monitoring tables in Vertica's `v_monitor` system schema. They have much more information for an administrator to work with. And even more, you should get familiar with Vertica's management console.

Comment: And, for syslog specifically, check out this part of the Vertica documentation: https://docs.vertica.com/23.4.x/en/admin/monitoring/monitoring-events/configuring-event-reporting/configuring-reporting-syslog/